# mysql shutdown unexpectedly xampp, socket created on IP: '::' error log

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am facing a problem in xampp, mysql doesn't running, i have searched a lot for a solution and tried a many of them, but no one fixed, my problem, i think the error log is different this time,
errors log :

```
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk 
size = 16M
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. 
Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 113908; transaction id 9
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200121 13:12:04
2020-01-21 13:12:04 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, i had to re-install xampp again :(